# Load website in a subdirectory using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to make a fully working backup of the actual site in a subdirectory, but I don't understand why it doesn't work, I mean the website is not showing correctly.

Here is the .htaccess code of the root directory. I need to make a backup in a subdirectory "/old/".

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://www.%example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/css/(.*) /css/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/js/(.*) /js/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/fonts/(.*) /fonts/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/images/(.*) /images/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/templates/(.*) /templates/$2 [L]


RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/css/(.*) /css/$2 [L]
> RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/js/(.*) /js/$2 [L]
> RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/fonts/(.*) /fonts/$2 [L]
> RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/images/(.*) /images/$2 [L]
> RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/templates/(.*) /templates/$2 [L]
>
> RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L]
> RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L]
> RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L]
> RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L]
> ```

You just need to remove the slash prefix from all the *substitution* strings in the above directives. You can then use the same `.htaccess` file in both the root and in the backup subdirectory.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/css/(.*) css/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/js/(.*) js/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/fonts/(.*) fonts/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/images/(.*) images/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/templates/(.*) templates/$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

Removing the slash prefix makes the substitution relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file.

These 9 directives can be reduced/simplified into 2 if you wish:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/((?:css|js|fonts|images|templates)/.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/[^/]*){1,3}$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

**UPDATE:** I've fixed the regex in the 2nd "simplified" rule since when there is only one path segment the trailing slash is mandatory (previously it would not have matched if the trailing slash was included). For two and three path segments the trailing slash is effectively *optional* and for four path segments, there should be no trailing slash. Although whether that was really the intention of the original directives is another matter. The 2nd "simplified" rule now matches that behaviour. (Previously, it did not permit a trailing slash with any number of path segments.)

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
> RewriteRule ^ - [L]
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)?example\.com$ [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
> RewriteRule .? http://www.%example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
> ```

You should reverse the order of these two rules. Otherwise, the first rule will prevent the canonical redirect (that prefixes the www subdomain) from happening on direct file requests.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks, although I've spotted an error in the regex of the 2nd "simplified" rule. When there is just one path segment, the original rule required a trailing slash (although this is not enforced when there are 2+ path segments and omitted entirely when there are 4 path segments!). My original simplified rule would not have matched if a trailing slash was present. I've updated my answer and fixed this regex so it behaves the same as the original directives.